# How to plot data coming async in a chartjs chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, angularfire2

I have a firebase database, I read the data using angularfire2, parse them in an array and pass this back to the user, where it should be plotted in a chartjs chart

So far I do have a service that returns a promise, if resolved it will return an array. I have tried different ways of setting the data.

the service function

```
getChart()
  {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let dates: string[] = [];
      let values: number[] = [];
      let response: any = [];

      let res: Observable<BodyFat[]> = this.db.list(this.BASE_PATH, ref => ref.orderByChild(this.DATE).limitToLast(40)).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(items => {
      return items.map(item => {
        let bodyfat = new BodyFat;
        bodyfat.id = item.payload.key;
        bodyfat.date = new Date(item.payload.child(this.DATE).val());
        bodyfat.fat = item.payload.child(this.FAT).val();

        return bodyfat;
      })
    }));

    let i: number = 0;

    res.subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach(element => {

        i++;

        var shortDate = moment(element.date).format('DD.MM.YYYY');

        if(dates.indexOf(shortDate) === -1)
        {
          dates.push(shortDate);
          values.push(element.fat);
        }

        if(i === data.length-1)
        {
          response = {...}

        resolve(response);
        }
      });
    });
    });

    return promise;
  }
```

the method call looks like

```
var bodyFatChartInstance = new Chart(this.bodyfatRef.nativeElement);

this.bodyfatService.getChart().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  document.getElementById('bodyFatChart').innerHTML = data.toString();
});

this.bodyFat = bodyFatChartInstance;
```

If the arry is synchronusly returned, the chart is plotted just fine, the array returned looks just fine, but somehow the chart plotting isn't working fine.

So far the console showed me different errors, depending how i tried to set the data. Currently i get the following one

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting and reading I figured how, I don't know if it is the best or correct way but it's working.

The service is fine, the call haves to look like

```
    var bodyFatChartInstance = new Chart(this.bodyfatRef.nativeElement, this.bodyfatService.getChartConfig());

    this.bodyfatService.getChart().then(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
      data["data"]["datasets"][0]["data"].forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
        bodyFatChartInstance.data.datasets[0].data.push(element);
      });

      data["data"]["labels"].forEach(element => {
       bodyFatChartInstance.data.labels.push(element); 
      });

      bodyFatChartInstance.update();
    });
```